# Dynamic Loading Files in NPM Modules as Plugins (ES6 Import)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am developing a NodeJS application, and was thinking about the best way to develop a plugin system. Currently, most components on the application are already decoupled in a way that they can be registered in and out to add and/or remove functionality. But currently, those components are still spread across many folders inside the app source. My goal would be to have a plugins folder, with a sub-folder for each plugin, and the application would scan said folder on startup to load the plugins. Also, as a nice plus, I'd love to load plugins from the node_modules (inspired by the way babel handles presets in version 6). I already have a fairly good idea how this system will work.

Now, my question is what is the best way to provide access to common files and classes, to the plugins. Let's say that I have a base class `Receiver`, and a plugin registers a custom receiver (which will extend the base class `Receiver`). How do I provide access for all theose classes to an external npm module without creating an object and passing each manually?

I use ES6 imports which replace the node's `require` function in my code, and use relative paths, but to be honest, I've never really understood how babel implements these module loaders and how could I use a dynamic module loader.

Comment: Uh oh, I don't think this is possible (without some fragile hacks). Passing the important stuff (classes, constants, functions) as the arguments to the plugins seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: https://medium.com/@timoxley/named-exports-as-the-default-export-api-670b1b554f65    https://learn.javascript.ru/modules https://habrahabr.ru/post/267639/